# Parse messages from multiline string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have following string

```
messages = """Jan 09, 07:03 AM - +91 12345 12345:‬ added ‪+91 45678 47263‬
Jan 10, 07:03 AM - +91 12345 12345: Hello
Jan 11, 07:03 AM - +91 12345 12345: How are you?.
Jan 12, 07:03 AM - +91 12345 12345: What's up?
"""
```

I want to parse above messages using regular expression and print only message

output should be

```
added ‪+91 45678 47263‬
Hello
How are you?.
What's up?
```

Comment: What about `re.split(':',message)` where message is one line of messages?

Comment: But it split time also

Comment: Then split, starting at an offset: `re.split(':',message[15])`. The only problem might be if a message contains ':'. So you will need to take the  results given by `split` and append them beginning at index 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to regex it:

```
for i in re.findall(".+:\s*(.*)", messages):
    print(i)
```

This doesn't handle the special chars you have in there though.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import re
result = [re.split('\d+:', line)[-1] for line in messages.split('\n')]
for item in result:
    print item
```

Comment: Yeah but if message contain ":" then?

Comment: Edited with `re` solution.

Answer (score 0):

python has [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) methods that will search a string left-to-right for a substring and return its position as an integer. It also has [`rfind`](http://32bit:odb:Driver=Lotus%20NotesSQL%20Driver%20(*.nsf);Database=aba%5CAPUHOTSHEET.nsf;Server=PHXAPPS3/USAIR;UID=Eric%20Lohmar/MAE/USAIR;PWD=__EncPwd1__;MaxVarcharLen=4096;) and [`rindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex) that do the same, but they search right to left. So you can split the text on newline characters and slice each line. Could look something like this:

```
messages = """Jan 09, 07:03 AM - +91 12345 12345:‬ added ‪+91 45678 47263‬
Jan 10, 07:03 AM - +91 12345 12345: Hello
Jan 11, 07:03 AM - +91 12345 12345: How are you?.
Jan 12, 07:03 AM - +91 12345 12345: What's up?
"""

for line in messages.split('\n'):
    if line:
        print(line[line.rindex(':') + 2:])
```

yields output:

```
added ‪+91 45678 47263‬
Hello
How are you?.
What's up?
```

The `if line:` was thrown in there because the final `"""` was on a new line which would have come up as an empty string and `index`/`rindex` throws an error if it can't find the substring in the string. If that is an issue, you can use the `find` or `rfind` methods which return -1 instead of throwing an error.

It is also worth noting that unexpected results will show up if the message itself has a `:` in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string and want to get all the text after the FIRST ":", try something like this:

```
myString = "Jan 10, 07:03 AM - +91 12345 12345: Hello"
index = myString.find(":") # Gets index of first ":" in the myString variable
message = myString[index:] # Starts at index and gets everything afterwards
# message is now ": Hello"
```

If you want to remove the colon from the message, just add 1 to the index

```
message = myString[index+1:] # message is now " Hello"
```

Then you can do this for each line by using messages.split('\n') as shown below

```
for line in messages.split('\n'):
    index = line.find(':') # Gets index of first ":" in line
    message = line[index+1:]
    print message
```